# How to compare the 2 arrays and obtain unique value and set the value in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I was trying to compare 2 different api calls from which i am able to make out 2 different arrays of ids , So i am trying to filter out the ids which already exist in array2 , and for the remaining ids i am trying to set the state , could anyone help me with it ?

code so far :

```
    const [ prevAdmins , setPrevAdmins ] = useState<any>([]);
    const [options, setOptions] = useState([{value: "", label: ""}]);

//API 1 CALL 
get_user_groups({bot_id:params.botid , group_id:params.userid}).then((res) => {
             setDetails(res?.data?.data[0]);
             setGroupName(res?.data?.data[0].name)
             let prevAdmins: any = [];
             res?.data?.data[0]?.join_details.map((prevJoinee , idx) => {
              prevAdmins.push(prevJoinee.user_id)
              setPrevAdmins(prevAdmins)
             })
           });

//OUTPUT FOR API 1 "prevAdmins": ['61dfcfb71f492f4f4f589e93', '61dedd23bd15322626dd7539']

//2nd API CALL : 
  get_followers({bot_id:params.botid}).then((res) => {
            if(res.data.data){
              let option: any = [];
              let allAdmins: any = [];
              res.data.data.map((admin, index) => {
                allAdmins.push(admin._id);
                if(!prevAdmins.includes(allAdmins)){
                  option.push({value: admin._id, label: admin.displayName})
                 }
                })
                setOptions(option);
            }
          })

//OUTPUT FOR API 2 : ['61dfd02a1f492f4f4f589f00', '61dfcfb71f492f4f4f589e93', '61dedd23bd15322626dd7539']
```

Now what i am trying is to exclude the ids which is already present in Array 1 and **setOptions** should store the ids which are not excluded.

Regards !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the unique values form your api calls, You can use `Set` instead of an array.

Please refer: https://www.javatpoint.com/typescript-set

Answer (score 0):

You can use spread operator to combine two arrays and then convert it to Set and make an array from that Set. It will be unique.

roughly you can do something similar to this approach.

```
let array1 = [1,2,4]
let array2 = [4,3,5,6]

let combinedArray = [...array1, ...array2]
let arraySet = new Set(combinedArray)
let uniqueArray = Array.from(arraySet)
console.log(uniqueArray)
```

spread operator will combine two arrays but it will have duplicate values too.
when you convert it into Set, it will remove any duplicate values.

Then you can simply generate an array from that Set variable.

You can do this to make it short too.

```
let uniqueArray = Array.from(new Set([...array1, ...array2]))
```

after you have the unique array you can simply set state with the uniqueArray variable.

In your case:

if you are getting these two arrays.

```
let arr1 = ['61dfcfb71f492f4f4f589e93', '61dedd23bd15322626dd7539']
let arr2 =['61dfd02a1f492f4f4f589f00', '61dfcfb71f492f4f4f589e93', '61dedd23bd15322626dd7539']
```

you can do something like this

```
let uniqueArray = Array.from(new Set([...arr1, ...arr2]))
console.log(uniqueArray)
```

[image]

Comment: this answer returns me the complete Array 2 itself , no changes @shehzad ahmed

Comment: can you provide both of your arrays in the question?

Comment: arr1 = ['61dfcfb71f492f4f4f589e93', '61dedd23bd15322626dd7539'] , arr2 =['61dfd02a1f492f4f4f589f00', '61dfcfb71f492f4f4f589e93', '61dedd23bd15322626dd7539']

let uniqueArray = Array.from(new Set([...array1, ...array2]))
it returns me one array but it also shows the duplicates with no repeat aswell

Comment: can you also provide your second array?

Comment: i received the same answer as yours , what i am expecting after comparing the 2 arrays and removing the ids which are same in both arrays so the final output should be 
: ['61dfd02a1f492f4f4f589f00'] 

not all the 3 ,

Comment: check this solution, it might help you. http://jsfiddle.net/BumbleB2na/XvgTb/1/